# Merge lists in list if one element is the same

Tags: python

I have a rather large list of lists (approx. 4k lists), with each list containing a name and a number.

The format is something like this:

```
mylist = [['Smith, Karen','10'],['Miller, Michael','20'],['Smith, Karen','30'],['Taylor, Peter','95']]
```

I am looking for a way to consolidate this list, such that duplicate names will be consolidated into one list with the pertaining numbers added up. After the operation, this example list of lists should look like this:

```
mylist = [['Smith, Karen','40'],['Miller, Michael','20'],['Taylor, Peter','95']]
```

Any ideas how to go about this? I did extract all the duplicate names, but that is as far as I got.

Comment: What have you tried? What language, even? Looks like it could be Python, in which case a `defaultdict` or `Counter` would do most of the work.

Comment: Sorry for this. Yes, this is a python question. Can you elaborate on your suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_list = [['Smith, Karen', '10'], ['Miller, Michael', '20'], ['Smith, Karen', '30'], ['Taylor, Peter', '95']]
data = defaultdict(int)
for entry in input_list:
    data[entry[0]] += int(entry[1])
final_list = [[k, v] for k, v in data.items()]
print(final_list)
```

output

```
[['Smith, Karen', 40], ['Miller, Michael', 20], ['Taylor, Peter', 95]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is saying that the number is associated to the name. That's what dictionaries are for. So, don't use lists, use a dictionary.

```
output = dict()
for element in mylist:
    output[element[0]] = output.get(element[0], 0) + int(element[1])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, I could use a dictionary for the consolidated data set. The original list contains duplicate names, so it couldn't exist as a dictionary.